# How to retrieve only headers of the email not body (Fetchmail or Getmail)

Tags: email

How I can to get only headers of the mail, to download the message body later.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

POP3 offers the `TOP <message #> <n>` command to retrieve headers and first `<n>` lines of the message body. Simply set `n = 0`.

IMAP offers the `FETCH <message #>  body[header]` command to retrieve only the headers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How to provide this in fetchmail configuration?